# Renaming existing file in java

Tags: java, file

I am programming a basic notepad program and I want it to be able to rename files from the command line. If the user writes "rename" to scanner, the program changes the note's file name according to input, like `-rename stack`. But if user enter two new note names. Program will error like `Invalid note name for renaming. It contains ' '. Enter one word.`. If a proposed name is used by an existing file, the program will print `File already exists`.

How can i do this:

-rename stack
**Enter new note name?**
stack over
**Invalid note name for renaming. It contains 'over'. Enter one word**
-rename stack
**Enter new note name?**
over
**File already exists**

This is what I've written so far:

```
           ...
           else if (noteNameSplited[0].equals("rename")) {

            File file = new File(noteNameSplited[1]+".ncat");

            if(!file.exists()) {
                System.out.println("File does not exist !");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Enter the new note name");
                String data=scan.nextLine();
                File file2 = new File(data+".ncat");
                file.renameTo(file2);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Read the documentation of the `Files` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
public boolean renameTo(File dest) {
    SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (security != null) {
        security.checkWrite(path);
        security.checkWrite(dest.path);
    }
    return fs.rename(this, dest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

https://github.com/openstreetmap/osmosis/blob/master/osmosis-core/src/main/java/org/openstreetmap/osmosis/core/util/AtomicFileCreator.java#L50

```
    if (!tmpFile.exists()) {
        throw new OsmosisRuntimeException("Can't rename non-existent file " + tmpFile + ".");
    }

    // Delete the existing file if it exists.
    if (file.exists()) {
        if (!file.delete()) {
            throw new OsmosisRuntimeException("Unable to delete file " + file + ".");
        }
    }

    // Rename the new file to the existing file.
    if (!tmpFile.renameTo(file)) {
        throw new OsmosisRuntimeException(
                "Unable to rename file " + tmpFile + " to " + file + ".");
    }
```